# Rounding a number off to certain number of places Java

Tags: java

Good afternoon

Would just like to know what the easiest way would be of rounding a value of to a certain number of decimal places in Java.

With C#.

```
double answer;
double numberOne;
double numberTwo;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers for your calculation");

numberOne = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
numberTwo = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
answer = numberOne / numberTwo;

Console.WriteLine(answer);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(answer, 3));
```

Kind regards

Comment: Look into using either a DecimalFormat object or String.format(...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double d = 3.12345;

DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
double twoDecimal =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(d));
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I guess

```
(double)Math.round(answer * 1000) / 1000;
```

would do the trick. There might be other options though!

Edit: Just found this thread for a more detailed discussion:

[How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: @BartKiers Sorry about that. I can only see what I can see.

Comment: @Willem, yeah, the Q&A you linked to contains much more info on rounding with Java (this question should really be closed as a duplicate).

Comment: +1: A slightly shorter answer `Math.round(answer*1000)/1000.0`

Answer (score 3):

Look into using either a DecimalFormat object or String.format(...). For example

```
  double foo = 3.14159265;

  // note that printf uses the same formatter as Formatter 
  //as does String.format(...)
  System.out.printf("%.3f%n", foo);

  DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
  System.out.println(dFormat.format(foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster way to round (provided the number is not too large)

```
double d = (long)(x > 0 ? x * 1000 + 0.5 : x * 1000 - 0.5)/1e3;
```

Its about 3x faster than using Math.round (but will fail for numbers greater than 9 million trillion ;)